# Segmentation Fault with sprintf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm making a makefile creator, but I'm stuck in this error on sprintf, the most curios thing is that I have multiple sprintf before the one with the error and they work fine.

Here's the code:

```
if ( WIFEXITED(stat)  ){

    if ( WEXITSTATUS(stat) ) {

        if ( cFiles == 0 && cFolders == 0 ) {
            Crear(path);
        }

        cFolders = 1;
        TEMP = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name) + 25 ) );

        if ( TEMP == NULL ) {
            perror("Malloc Error: ");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ( sprintf(TEMP, "\n%s/%s.a: force\n\t$(MAKE) -C %s\n",direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name) < 0 ) {
        perror("Sprintf Error: ");
        exit(1);
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO,TEMP,strlen(TEMP));
        f.name = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name)*2 + 3 ) );

        if ( f.name = NULL ) {
            perror("Malloc Error: ");
            exit(1);
        } 
            //This is the one with the problem!!!       
            if ( sprintf(f.name, "%s/%s.a", direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name) < 0 ) {
            perror("Sprintf Error: ");
            exit(1);
        }

        l = AddToList(l,&f);
    }
}
```

Comment: My best guess is that one of the strings isn't null terminated. I had that problem a couple times when I was first learning C.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are allocating TEMP to be large enough

```
TEMP = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name) + 25 ) );
```

should be:

```
TEMP = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name)*3 + 25 + 1 ) );
```

You are printing d_name three times, and you also need an extra byte for the null terminator.

Likewise, on this line:

```
   f.name = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name)*2 + 3 ) );
```

should be

```
   f.name = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name)*2 + 3 + 1) );
```

to account for the null terminator.

Using asserts like this can help make sure your calculations are right:

```
    int TEMP_size = strlen(direntp->d_name)*3 + 25 + 1; 
    TEMP = malloc(sizeof(char)*TEMP_size);

    if ( TEMP == NULL ) {
        perror("Malloc Error: ");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( sprintf(TEMP, "\n%s/%s.a: force\n\t$(MAKE) -C %s\n",direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name) < 0 ) {
      perror("Sprintf Error: ");
      exit(1);
    }
    assert(strlen(TEMP)+1==TEMP_size);
```

Comment: Sorry the code that I posted was the old one and the TEMP allocation was fixed, but the segmentation fault doesn't come from TEMP, but from sprintf(f.name.....). That is what I found weird, even with f.name = malloc( sizeof(char)*( strlen(direntp->d_name)*2 + 3 + 1) ) still launch the same error.

Answer (score 0):

"%s/%s.a", so i think if "%s" is of length n, then the whole string would take n*2+1+1+1+1=2n+4 rather than 2n+3... don't forget the terminating '\0',,,
but as for whether this should cause a segmentation fault... i have no idea...

//Yeah, lots of errors concerning the number of bytes to allocate in this piece of code ...

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate enougth memory for this sprintf:

```
sprintf(TEMP, "\n%s/%s.a: force\n\t$(MAKE) -C %s\n",direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name
```

You allocate sizeof(direntp->d_name) +25 but i see 25 char + 3* sizeof(direntp->d_name) +1 extra char (your \0 that indicate the end of your string)

regards

Comment: Thanks but like I said in the other comments, that wasn't the error, though TEMP now has the correction the seg fault is coming from sprintf(f.name.....)

Comment: sprintf(f.name, "%s/%s.a", direntp->d_name, direntp->d_name, I see 2* strlen(direntp->d_name) + 3 char + 1 extra char (\0 for end of string). You allocated 2*strlen(direntp->d_name) + 3 char only. You miss the \0 space of your string. Edit arf didn't see you tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes in addition to previous answers:

1. Most of modern Unix-like systems have asprintf() and vasprintf() in standard library which allocates buffer by themselves. Using them is simpler than calculating needed size, allocate and call sprintf(), even if they overallocate for a bit.
2. Filling of buffer and then printing it to stdout using write() looks like unnessessary complication over simple printf(). Using stdio for such tasks is much better unless you use something that stdio can't stably handle (as non-blocking I/O).
3. The task you are performing is much better fitting into some scripting language (Perl, Python, Tcl, Ruby, whatever), unless some external weird circumstances are forcing you to use C; C is supposed in Unix way to fulfil areas more closer to kernel and low level. See e.g. ["The Art of Unix Programming"](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/languageschapter.html) for reasoning.

Comment: It's a project from my university, that's why I have to use C, I know asprintf() is better but I have some restrictions as what commands I can use.